# primary telephone number with three text field

Tags: html, css

I would like to create the following:

[image]

And I did as follows:

```
<span>* Primary Phone:</span>
        <input name="prim1" type="text" id="prim1" class="required">
        <input name="prim2" type="text" id="prim2" class="required">
        <input name="prim3" type="text" id="prim3" class="required">
```

however I get:

[image]

I'd like to make the text smaller by specifying the width however it doesn't do that. I also need a way to do the validation for this using jQuery, how can I do it if it's a separate text field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend just setting the width on all required fields, I believe you need to update your html to better reflect what you are trying to convey and I wouldn't necessarily do it in the CSS as this is data that should be present even without styling. I would do something like:

```
<span>* Primary Phone:</span>
<input name="prim1" type="text" id="prim1" size="3" class="required">
<input name="prim2" type="text" id="prim2" size="3" class="required">
<input name="prim3" type="text" id="prim3" size="4" class="required">
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.last-child.com/input-size-in-html-and-css/) for why input size would be acceptable where font size typically isn't.

For more on validation and preventing invalid characters, I would use [JQuery Validation](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate) or an Autotabber (like http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/) with masking built in.

Comment: How do I use jQuery validator for case like this?

Comment: Take a look at this question where they do something similar for date of birth. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289086/jquery-validate-multiple-fields-with-one-error

Comment: also, how do I post three fields into one POST name?

Answer (score 3):

In your css

```css
#prim1, #prim2, #prim3 { width: 50px; display:inline-block; }
```

The jQuery validation plugin will take care of each element marked 'required'

Comment: Thanks @Joe, It would be best to use ID's for the input fields.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than apply the style to `input.required`, I'd apply it on the 3 ID's, otherwise every input that has `class="required"` (which is needed for the validation) will be 50px wide.

```css
#prim1, #prim2, #prim3 { width: 50px; display:inline-block; }
```

Comment: Yes, I that would be best. I missed the Id's in the sample code. Nice catch.