# How to make Inputs in Boxes in HTML form as shown in image?

Tags: jquery, html

How to make Inputs in Boxes, in an HTML form as shown in the bellow image. Also, how should I collect all the input.

I'd like to collect the values of the inputs and append them to a single variable. I don't know how to make this.

[image]

Comment: try to this http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/SEXAj/

Comment: You might find this useful [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369448/primary-telephone-number-with-three-text-field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369448/primary-telephone-number-with-three-text-field)

Comment: Try to this plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/