# How to hide error messages and have one error message jQuery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validate Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) and I want to be able to hide the error messages next to my inputs and have a main error message at the bottom, I have this working kind of but the error messages are showing next to my input fields. (Obviously I would clean up the styling if i was using it).

As you can see at the bottom it is telling me there are 4 errors see details below.. I want this to stay but not the error messages and styling above?

[image]

```
$( ".form-group-rules" ).validate({ 
    rules: {
        rule_name: {
            required: true
        },
        rule_desc: {
            required: false
        },
        rule_type: {
            required: true
        },  
        vali_type: {
            required: true
        },
        tran_type: {
            required: true
        },
        vali_fields: {
            required: true
        },
        acct_sel: {
            required: true
        }               
    },   
  messages: {
    rule_name: "Please enter a rule name",
    rule_type: "Please select a rule type", 
    vali_fields: "Please select a validation field",
    tran_type: "Please select at least 1 transaction type",
    vali_type: "Please select a valiation type",
    acct_sel: "Please select at least 1 account"
  },
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $(".error-container").html("Your form contains "
      + this.numberOfInvalids()
      + " errors, see details below.");
    this.defaultShowErrors();
  }    
});
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716649/using-jquery-validate-plugin-to-output-a-single-error-message-for-multiple-field

Comment: @Pugazh thanks for this, this was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

May be use the Validator method

```
errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
    return true;
  }
```

It will not append the error to the inputs.

Comment: This is unnecessary additional code, because the OP is programmatically putting these messages in place with `this.defaultShowErrors()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the error messages with CSS:

```
span.error {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `showErrors` will automatically suppress the default messages next to each input element.

You're creating your own issue because **`.defaultShowErrors()` is the method for putting back the default messages**.

Simply remove `this.defaultShowErrors()`...

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $(".error-container").html("Your form contains "
      + this.numberOfInvalids()
      + " errors, see details below.");
    this.defaultShowErrors();  // <- REMOVE THIS LINE
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/jmdnxedq/**