# jQuery validation plugin. How can I have 1 message for several rules?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This is a snippet of javascript code

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        "studentid": {
            required: true
            , digits: true
            , maxlength: 7
            , minlength: 7
        }
```

I would like to have 1 message for required, digits, maxlength and minlength rules. I want this text to display: "Invalid format"

I know I can specify a message for each rule individually like:

```
  messages: {
    name: {
      required: "We need your email address to contact you",
      minlength: jQuery.validator.format("At least {0} characters required!")
    }
  }
```

But is it possible to have a shortcut? thanks! :)

Comment: [this may help you](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-refactoring-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have 1 message for `required`, `digits`, `maxlength` and `minlength` rules. I want this text to display: `"Invalid format"`

You are allowed to assign a single message to the field and it will apply to all rules for that field...

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        studentid: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            maxlength: 7,
            minlength: 7
        }
    },
    messages: {
        studentid: "Invalid Format"  // same message for all rules on this field
    }
});
```

DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/4xayL7bk/](http://jsfiddle.net/4xayL7bk/)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this like:

```
var errorMsg = "Invalid Format";

messages: {
    name: {
      required: errorMsg,
      minlength: errorMsg
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but that's not what I had in mind... I'm still specifying the rules individually. I want to avoid that. :)

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716649/using-jquery-validate-plugin-to-output-a-single-error-message-for-multiple-field
It will help you in achieving this.